# Java one-time event scheduling

Tags: java, activemq-classic, scheduler

Can you please advise if there are any solutions which allows to schedule some type of one-time event for specific time (not cron-style) and easily manage it via UI and APi.
We have checked on [ActiveMQ delayed messages](http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html) but the main concert is that there is no easy way to re-schedule the event. The only option is to totally remove old event and create new one. And even for this solution there is no UI, only programmatic.

Comment: Quartz perhaps? http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: Quartz is just small library without any UI for monitoring/managing.

Comment: Quartz can be managed using JMX. There is a project to provide a web-based interface to this functionality -- https://code.google.com/archive/p/myschedule/ -- but I don't know its status. EJBs offer timer functionality; depending on the appserver, there might be some user interface to manage this.

Answer (score 1):

Sending a message to the broker with the property "AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY" then that schedules a one time only delayed message.  Only when you add a repeat value does the message get rescheduled.  You can use the management bits of the scheduled message to create your own UI as you can query and cancel jobs by id or in windows etc.

Comment: Regarding custom UI. This is something we would like to avoid. Maybe there are another(commercial?) solution that support that functionality from the scratch.

Comment: None that I'm aware of.